# C++ Template class with a static const member instance of itself

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization, constants

A static const member of a template class should be initilized  as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class TypeA{
public:
   static const int INSTANCE = 1;
};
```

What is the correct syntax/is is possible if we want an instance of class TypeA, rather than an int?

Eg:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class TypeA{
public:
    T mData;
    TypeA(T data) : mData(data){}

    static const TypeA<T> INSTANCE = TypeA<T>(1);
};


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    std::cout << TypeA<int>::INSTANCE.mData << std::endl;
}
```

This produces the error (gcc):

```
main.cpp||In instantiation of 'class TypeA<int>':|
main.cpp|14|required from here|
main.cpp|9|error: in-class initialization of static data member 'const TypeA<int> TypeA<int>::INSTANCE' of incomplete type|
main.cpp||In instantiation of 'const TypeA<int> TypeA<int>::INSTANCE':|
main.cpp|14|required from here|
main.cpp|9|error: in-class initialization of static data member 'const TypeA<int> TypeA<int>::INSTANCE' of non-literal type|
main.cpp|9|error: non-constant in-class initialization invalid for static member 'TypeA<int>::INSTANCE'|
main.cpp|9|error: (an out of class initialization is required)|
main.cpp|9|error: 'TypeA<int>::INSTANCE' cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared|
||=== Build finished: 5 errors, 4 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply follow the instructions the compiler gives you:

> main.cpp|9|error: in-class initialization of static data member 'const TypeA TypeA::INSTANCE' of incomplete type|

You can't initialize a type that has not yet been completely declared. So, you have to move the initialization out of the class declaration:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class TypeA{
public:
    T mData;
    TypeA(T data) : mData(data){}

    static const TypeA<T> INSTANCE;
};

template <typename T>
const TypeA<T> TypeA<T>::INSTANCE = TypeA<T>(1);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    std::cout << TypeA<int>::INSTANCE.mData << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize INSTANCE inside the class. You need to do it later.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
class TypeA{
public:
    T mData;
    TypeA(T data) : mData(data){}
    static const TypeA<T> INSTANCE;
};
template <typename T> const TypeA<T> TypeA<T>::INSTANCE=TypeA<T>(1);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    std::cout << TypeA<int>::INSTANCE.mData << std::endl;
}
```